# Openoffice file as xlsx

Tags: .net, excel, spreadsheet, openoffice.org

I'm generating a file with OpenOffice library in C#

When I'm saving, I'm doing this:

```
XStorable2 xs = (XStorable2)oDoc;
PropertyValue[] propVals2 = new PropertyValue[1];
propVals2[0] = new PropertyValue();
propVals2.Name = "FilterName";
propVals2.Value = uno.Any("MS Excel 97");

xs.storeToURL(fileName, propVals2);
```

At this point everything is fine and the file is generated with Excel 97 format...

Now, I want to change it to save in XLSX format, so I'm guessing I need to change line # 5... but I cant find the value for that format.

I've tried:

```
propVals2.Value = uno.Any("Calc MS Excel 2007 XML");
```

But it just throws an empty message exception...

I also tried to use xs.storeAsURL... but the same problem..

Thanks, I appreciate any help.